# Missing blame information for the following files SonarQube Error

Tags: sonarqube

I couldnt run my maven project in sonarqube using command mvn sonar:sonar.
It results with the error : **Missing blame information for the following files**.
But a normal helloworld program run successfully and it got added in the projects tab of sonarqubes.

Kindly help me to sort out this error.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add more detail: does it enumerate all the file in your project or just a few? Also, are the listed files modified or added after the project is checked out?

Answer (score 16):

If you have no commited file, you can't run command mvn sonar:sonar.
You need commit any change into your branch and after run mvn sonar:sonar.
This fix me.

Answer (score 9):

I was also running a maven sonar:sonar command from eclipse neon (jboss developer studio) and also saw this warning in the logs of the console.

I had files that were changed locally but I didn't commit or push them to the git repo. I pushed all files to the origin and the warning disappeared.

Comment: a commit would have been sufficient, though. A push is not necessary.